# How to split a cell of text and transpose it into column and split it again?

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched many posts, forums, tutorials, I tried combine some of them, but nothing really worked for me. Now I write some code, that by logic I learn from other programming languages it should work, but I'm missing few steps.

Let's assume I have string like this
`Test User <TUser@my-domain.pl>; Test User2 <TUser2@my-domain.pl>; Test User3 <TUser3@my-domain.pl>; Test User4 <TUser4@my-domain.pl>;`

I paste that into cell, let's say `A1`. My goal is to be left with Test User or TUser for each smaller string.

I can achive my goal by doing so:

1. Click Text as columns -> Delimited -> Other `;`, now each string is in separate column
2. Copy whole A row and paste it with transpose(rotate), so each string is in separate row
3. Now easiest way is to use Text as columns, by `<` delimiter. So all I'm left with is `Name Surname` in one cell and rest in other

I want to achive that, by clicking on the button of course.

My code so far:

```
Sub GetName()

Dim WordList As String
Dim ArrayOfWords
Dim i, i2 As Integer

'Define my word list, based on cell
WordList = Cells(1, 1)

'Use SPLIT function to convert the string to an array
ArrayOfWords = Split(WordList, "<")

'Iterate through array, and put each string into new row cell
i = 2
i2 = 1
Do While (ThereIsNoMoreText)'That I cannot figure out

Cells(2, i).Value = ArrayOfWords(i2)

i = i + 1
i2 = i2 + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks for you help in advance and I hope I make it clear :)

Answer (score 4):

Fun little alternative:

```
Sub Test()

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(?:<.*?>)"
    arr = Split(.Replace([A1], ""), ";")
End With

With Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(arr))
    .Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    .Value = Application.Trim(.Value)
End With

End Sub
```

Obviously, be sure to create an explicit sheet reference for `Cells`.

Comment: Witchcraft! Nice one.

Comment: Thanks @CLR, it however does not spill out the addresses like yours would, however OP mentioned *"My goal is to be left with Test User.."* so thought about doing some regular expressions fun =)

Comment: Congratulations on the gold badge. Well deserved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split by semicolon first.

Break the following apart to get the strings you need:

```
userlist = Split(Cells(1, 1).Value, ";")
i = 1
For Each user In userlist
    i = i + 1
    splituser = Split(user, "<")
    Cells(i, 1) = splituser(0)
    Cells(i, 2) = Mid(splituser(1), 1, Len(splituser(1)) - 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the methods shown in others answers (in particular the very impressive one by @JvdV) you could also try this.

This method does not use For…Next

```
Sub Users_Email_Split()
Dim aData As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST")
        aData = .Cells(1).Value
        aData = Left(aData, -2 + Len(aData))
        aData = Replace(aData, " <", """,""")
        aData = Replace(aData, ">; ", """;""")
        aData = "{""" & aData & """}"
        aData = Application.Evaluate(aData)
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(aData), UBound(aData, 2)).Value = aData
    End With
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**
If the `string` is expected to exceed the 255 characters limit for the Evaluate Function then you could use this method *(up to a max of 2086 characters)*.

This method a creates an `User Defined Name` with the array string as a formula, then applies the Name as a FormulaArray, and finally sets the value of the range.

```
Sub Users_Email_Split_Plus255()
Dim aData As Variant
Dim lR As Long, lC As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST")

        aData = .Cells(11, 1).Value
        aData = Left(aData, -2 + Len(aData))
        aData = Replace(aData, " <", """,""")
        aData = Replace(aData, ">; ", """;""")
        aData = "={""" & aData & """}"

        lR = 1 + UBound(Split(aData, ";"))
        lC = 1 + UBound(Split(Split(aData, ";")(0), ","))

        With .Cells(12, 2).Resize(lR, lC)

            .Worksheet.Names.Add Name:="_FmlX", RefersTo:=aData
            .FormulaArray = "=_FmlX"
            .Value = .Value

    End With: End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Be very cautious about the 255 chars limit of evaluate =)

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the construct a bit

```
Dim i As Long
Dim FirstPart As String, SecondPart As String
Dim ArrayOfWords
ArrayOfWords = Split(Cells(1, 1).Value, ";")
For i = LBound(ArrayOfWords) To UBound(ArrayOfWords)
    If InStr(1, ArrayOfWords(i), "<") > 0 Then
        FirstPart = Left(ArrayOfWords(i), InStr(1, ArrayOfWords(i), "<") - 1)
        SecondPart = Mid(ArrayOfWords(i), Len(FirstPart) + 1, Len(ArrayOfWords(i)))
        Debug.Print FirstPart & "--" & SecondPart
    End If
Next i
```